# In SceneKit, does an SCNLight of type SCNLightTypeAmbient ignore the categoryBitMask parameter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit

It seems to!

Here the categoryBitMask is ignored:

```
ambientLight = [SCNLight light];
ambientLight.color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.994 green:0.715 blue:0.179 alpha:1.000];
ambientLight.type = SCNLightTypeAmbient;
ambientLight.categoryBitMask = 1;
```

Here it works!

```
ambientLight = [SCNLight light];
ambientLight.color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.994 green:0.715 blue:0.179 alpha:1.000];
ambientLight.type = SCNLightTypeOmni;
ambientLight.categoryBitMask = 1;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's right, ambient light's categoryBitMask are ignored (documentation is lacking). Note that you can configure materials to ignore ambient lighting:

```
aMaterial.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = NO;
aMaterial.ambient.contents = blackColor; (the default)
```

Comment: Geez I struggled for a few days on this. It sucks when you put too much trust on official Apple documentation and couldn't figure out why.

Comment: Having struggled with the same, I'm sympathetic! However, the docs for the ambient light type do actually state: "A light that illuminates all objects in the scene from all directions." - just a shame they don't write for SCNLight "You can also use the categoryBitMask property to choose which nodes are illuminated by a light [unless type is set to .ambient]"!

Comment: So I can’t use the above to ignore default ambient lights on a node? I’m doing this with no results: text.materials.first!.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = false
        text.materials.first!.ambient.contents = UIColor(.black) where text is a SCNText