# How to stop SCNLight

Tags: ios, scenekit

I try to create a room without light inside a room with light but the walls are not stopping the light. If I point a spotlight to a wall it also shows on the other walls behind it even if i set castsshadow for the light and the walls. How can I solve this? I also tried by changing material properties, but I could not solve it.
Thanks!

Comment: I think that maybe you need to check your normals, I don't have any experience on sceneKit but in Ogre3D the normals of geometry are related to this behavior, I hope this help you in some way

Comment: Have you investigated the `categoryBitMask` property of `SCNLight`? I haven't used this myself but it reads like it may do the job if you can figure out how to apply it.

Comment: Thank you! categoryBitMask was the solution for the spotlight. If you want, you can post it as answer and I'll accept it. For ambient lights the solution is different: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29190578/in-scenekit-does-an-scnlight-of-type-scnlighttypeambient-ignore-the-categorybit.